# Install Multiprocessing python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Quite new to Python. I would like to install multiprocessing module of python. I am using python 3.6 and pip version 9.1.

I am getting an error which lead me to believe that since there isn't a multiprocessing module compatible with python 3 the below error can happen.

```
$ pip3 install multiprocessing
Collecting multiprocessing
  Using cached multiprocessing-2.6.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8m/2fkldrg12lg0qzlhpm8yvyq00000gn/T/pip-build-dqdczlx9/multiprocessing/setup.py", line 94
```

So, i installed the module using pip install multiprocessing which installed the module. I have written a lot of code in python 3 so i would like to use it and i am  using pycharm editor which i have configured to use python3. Now if i am executing the code in the editor it throws error like

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/kkk/Desktop/testing/multiprocessing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testing/multiprocessing.py", line 11, in <module>
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'Process'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

for the code

```
    import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print ('Worker')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

What can i do to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's part of the standard library; you already have it installed.

Comment: Your code worked without any problems. It looks like you are importing the `multiprocessing` module from `/Users/testing/multiprocessing.py` that does not look like a common path... Are you sure you are importing the right file? Could you post that file?

Comment: You named your code file the same as the module you would like to import. Then it imports the code file instead. Just rename your file and it works.

Comment: Thanks guys @KlausD. it seems the filename was the problem. I can accept that as answer. Well i was hoping to get a better error message from the compiler but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 44):

Since Python 2.6, `multiprocessing` is a built-in module.

It ships with Python, no specific installation step is needed.

Comment: In OP's case, he would have the same issue no matter if the `multiprocessing` module is part of the Standard library or a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is not with the `multiprocessing` module but with the **way you named your script** in which you're actually trying to import the `multiprocessing` module. You named it the same as the module, i.e. `multiprocessing.py`, so `import multiprocessing` actually imports the script itself instead of the Standard library's module.

That's because of the [way how Python searches modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in various locations and in a specific order:

> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

As you can see, the very first location where Python is looking for a module to be imported is the directory containing the input script. That's why it imports the script itself in your case. And your script doesn't contain the `Process` class you're trying to use, that's why you're getting the error `AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'Process'`.

And this issue is not specific to the `multiprocessing` module, it would happen with any module. Therefore **it's a good idea to not name your scripts the same as existing modules you're going to use (import)**.

Answer (score 1):

Change your filename to any except multiprocessing.py...
Your code is going to try import itself.